# Java SPI JARs not loaded from directory without setting -Djava.ext.dirs

Tags: java, jar

I can't get the Service Provider Interface to load an implementation from another JAR in the same directory. It only works when I use -Djava.ext.dirs=. on the command line. Should it not work without?

I have the following interface:

```
package playground;

public interface TestIface {
    public String test();
}
```

which is implemented here:

```
package playground;

public class TestImpl implements TestIface {
    public String test() {
        return "TEST";
    }
}
```

Here I try to load the implementation:

```
package playground;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
public class Lalala {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceLoader<TestIface> loader = ServiceLoader.load(TestIface.class);
        Iterator<TestIface> it = loader.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            TestIface a = it.next();
            System.out.println(a.test());
        }
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

}
```

The interface and the last class are packaged in main.jar, the implementation in impl.jar. 
main.jar has the Main class set and impl.jar has the META-INF/services/playground.TestIface file which contains "playground.TestImpl". Both JARs are in the same directory.
Running

```
java -jar main.jar
```

only prints "DONE", the implementation apparently is not found.

If I instead run

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=. -jar main.jar
```

it also prints "TEST" as it should.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the implementation from the other JAR not loaded unless I change the java.ext.dirs setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.ext.dirs` setting automatically adds all jar-files found in the specified directory to the main classloader, which is why the ServiceLoader can find and load `TestIface.class` (from the [Apidocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load%28java.lang.Class%29): "Creates a new service loader for the given service type, using the current thread's context class loader.").

But you should not use `java.ext.dirs` for this (see [here](http://www.scottmcmaster365.com/2009/03/perils-of-abusing-javaextdirs-property.html) for one of the dangers). And when you use `java -jar` you cannot use `java -cp` to set a classpath (you can only use one of them). This leaves you the option to use the [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load additional jars and then call `ServiceLoader.load(class from another jar)`.

Tip: to load other jar-files, use the location of the `main.jar` file as explained in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320542/3080094). Other variables (like startup directory) depend on how and from where Java was started and can easily result in not finding the other jar-files.

Comment: URLLoader works well, I just tried it, thanks.
So `java.ext.dirs` does not include the current directory by default?

Comment: No, it is meant to include additional jars installed with/added to your Java installation. Anyway it is more a 'system setup' thing than an 'application setup' thing - best to leave it alone.